# Create Documents with a default data type

Tags: mongodb, database

I want to create a new DB in mongodb, but i want to know if it's possible to create a new document with a default data type, dor example:

```
users = {name : 'string', age : 'integer', ...}
```

Ther's a way to do this?. O i need to just put the data and let mongodb change to the current data type..

Thanks!

Comment: Normally this would implemented within the applications ORM/ODM

Comment: yes, enforce the type in your application or ODM layer.

Comment: I will check ODM to apply it to my project.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As people are commenting, you would typically perform this type of validation within an ODM (Object Document Mapper) which if you are unfamiliar with you might try [this article](http://css.dzone.com/articles/era-object-document-mapping) for some background.

There are various implementations, depending on your language of choice, and there will be links to some from the [MongoDB drivers page](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/drivers/). But feel free to search.

Also of note, if you are just looking for something *lite* for use with JavaScript, the [js-schema](https://github.com/molnarg/js-schema) project might be of interest. And you could load it into your mongo shell by adding a `load(..)` call in your `.mongorc.js` file.

If you really want to play around like this, you might want a bunch of tools, so see [mesh](http://skratchdot.com/projects/mesh/) for a good example.

Comment: Thanks, i will check out the ODM, and  try to apply to my project, thank you very much for the help :D..